# JS Multiple file upload returns last file of loop

Tags: javascript, file, typescript, upload

I'm trying to do multiple file upload in JS.

I have this input in html

```
 <input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event,showFileNames)" multiple />
```

Then for onChange event this is executed

```
this.files = [].slice.call(event.target.files);
input.value = this.files;
```

**This.files** contains array of files to be uploaded.

Then after pressing "SUBMIT" , this is what I'm trying to do. This code is taken from previous similar thread's answer, but I still had no luck with it.

```
upload() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) { //for multiple files       
         var that = this;
         (function (file) {   
             var name = file.name;
             var reader = new FileReader();

             let parts = file.name.split(".");
             that.filename = parts[0];

             if (typeof (parts[1]) != "undefined")
                  that.ext = "." + parts[1];
             else
                  that.ext = "";

             reader.onload = function (e) {
                 var x = this.result;
                 let fileJSON = { "Filename": that.filename, "Extension": that.ext, "DateCreated": new Date(), "Data": btoa(this.result), "Sguid": that.tripsToEditx.sguid };
                 console.log(fileJSON);
             }
             reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        })(this.files[i]);
    }
}
```

variables name, ext and tripsToEditx are global variables, I couldn't access them via .this so I used

```
var that = this;
```

Anyway, I'm still getting the last selected file to be printed 3 times.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: `that.filename = parts[0];` if that is global, you will get the same file printed multiple times, as you have async code here.  Why not just use `parts[0]` as that's part of the closure.

Comment: Wow yeah no Idea how did I miss that.  Now the name and extension works, but Data is same for all. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: You can't just do a `btoa` on an ArrayBuffer, but you can do one on a view..  I'll post a snippet as an example..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

btoa, on an ArrayBuffer doesn't do what you might expect,..
<strike>But it does work on a Uint8Array, so if we create a view of the ArrayBuffer we can then btoa on this.</strike>

Below is an example, select some files, and view the output inside your browsers console.

ps.  you don't require the use of a function closure, if you can do `let` and `const`, as these will handle this for you.

```js
function arrayBufferToHex(buffer) {
  const view  = new Uint8Array( buffer );
  return Array.prototype.map.call(view, function(byte) {
    return ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2);
  }).join('');
}


document.querySelector("input").onchange = function () {  
  for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    const file = this.files[i];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    reader.onloadend = function (e) {     
      const splits = file.name.split(".");
      const fileJSON = { 
        "Filename": splits[0], 
        "Extension": splits[1], 
        "DateCreated": new Date(), 
        "Data": arrayBufferToHex(this.result), 
        "Sguid": "XYZ" };
      console.log(fileJSON);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Open browser console, to see results.</div>
<br>

<input type="file" multiple />
```

Comment: using btoa(view) gives error "Argument of type 'Uint8Array' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. ". Maybe its not possible in TS?

Comment: @user3465096 btoa on a view doesn't do what you might expect too,.. I've just done a quick update..

Comment: Seems to be working! Accepting as answer! One more question, if I need to save this DATA in Postgresql type "Bytea" maybe you could tell me if this conversion is ok?

Comment: @user3465096  I'm not a Postgresql, but hex is hex, so if there is a way of inserting data into postgresql using hex, I can't see there been an issue.